# How do I top-align two minipages in a figure?

Tags: floats, minipage

This code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    A

    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{schem_npn_transistor}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    B

    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{schem_pnp_transistor}
  \end{minipage}
  \label{schem:npn_pnp_transistor}
  \caption{\textbf{(A)} Enkel transistorkrets där NPN styr en
    lysdiod. Matning går via R2 och lysdiod till kollektorn,
    styrsignal går via R1 till basen. Emittern går direkt till
    jord. \textbf{(B)} Enkel transistorkrets där PNP styr en
    lysdiod. Matning går via R2 och lysdiod till kollektorn,
    styrsignal hölls hög till basen via R1. Emittern går även här
    direkt till jord.}
\end{figure}
```

produces this output:

[image]

The two images are center-aligned vertically, which doesn't look great. How can I make them top-align vertically, so the letters "A" and "B" line up perfectly?

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `minipage` and manually added captions (A and B)I would rather use `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{schem_npn_transistor}
\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=4cm]{schem_pnp_transistor}
\caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{\textbf{(A)} Enkel transistorkrets där NPN styr en
    lysdiod. Matning går via R2 och lysdiod till kollektorn,
    styrsignal går via R1 till basen. Emittern går direkt till
    jord. \textbf{(B)} Enkel transistorkrets där PNP styr en
    lysdiod. Matning går via R2 och lysdiod till kollektorn,
    styrsignal hölls hög till basen via R1. Emittern går även här
    direkt till jord.}
  \label{schem:npn_pnp_transistor}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: If you like to have correct referencing of figure `\label` command had to be after `caption` command.

Comment: What makes you want to use subfigure instead of minipage? What's the pro/con between the two?

Comment: @bos, compare results! You not observe differences? Which one gives nice result to your opinion? BTW,  using `subfigure` enable simple referencih it in text .... I use `minipage` when I need to use two serial numbered captions.